# How to make clickable area of a logo the same size as the logo for a navbar?

Tags: html, css

I'm a problem with my logo in the navbar. When I hover over my logo, it lets me hover more than it should. Like some pixels more. But when I lower the resolution, for like a phone, the logo ends up taking up all the space before the hamburger on the right side of the nav.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 2px 5px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 3px -1px;
}

nav img {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav a {}

.fa-bars {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- FontAwesome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aaefe49bc9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png"></a>
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the anchor is large then the image for 3 reasons. (Apply `a { border: 1px solid red;` to demonstrate it):

1. The CSS line`nav img { width: 50%; }` let the image only contain 50%
   of the width of the anchor. Means the anchor is twice as wide as
   necessary.
2. The line `nav img { padding: 10px 0; }` also adds extra space inside the anchor.
3. The image is an inline-element and as such as a inline decender space. Use `img { display: block; }` to remove it.

```css
/* changes */
nav img {
  display: block
}

/* apply this instead of the images padding */
nav a {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

/* Original CSS */
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 2px 5px -1px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 1px 3px -1px;
}

/* remove this part
nav img {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
*/

nav a {}

.fa-bars {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- FontAwesome -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/aaefe49bc9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.png"></a>
    
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </nav>
</div>
```